# Rails 4: Access database from generators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating a generator in Rails 4. I want to be able to access the database before copying files to load into the templates. However, when trying to access the database, I get the error: `uninitialized constant Model (NameError)`

Is there a way to access the model and database from a generator?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it in generators, but this should allow you to acccess database out of defined classes.

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'select * from users`